# Can't import a .tlb to my DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, sdk, mfc

I am creating a C++ MFC DLL based on a third party SDK in Visual Studio 2008. The SDK provides a TLB folder, a Lib folder (.lib only), an Include folder (.h and .hpp only) and a Bin folder (some exes, DLL and .ax files). I tried to link the SDK library to my DLL in the following way:

- C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories - Bin, Include and TLB folder (just in case);
- Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories - Lib and Bin;
- Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies - the .lib's in the Lib folder

Doing things this way I get compiling errors due to linking problems (undeclared indentifiers and such), so I added an import line for the TLB's:

```
#import "C:\Path\To\Tlb.tlb" raw_interfaces_only, raw_native_types, no_namespace, named_guids
```

This pops another compiling errors about type redefinitions:

```
error C2011: '_SYSTEMTIME' : 'struct' type redefinition
```

What am I missing? I am quite new to Windows programming.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why _SYSTEMTIME is redefined when it is defined in `<Windows.h>` or something brought in by it.

Anyway, try removing no_namespaces from the #import directive. Namespaces are there to avoid name clashes like these.

Comment: Thank you very much. I took that out and searched for the namespace in order to use it in my code. It now compiles and runs.

Answer (score 1):

You try to import type library which exposes object which is already defined.

From where you got this library?

You can remove

> no_namespace

but it may help only if object in type library is defined within other namespace then global.

You can also try only one attribute for import directive

> raw_interfaces_only

It depends on what you want to achieve/import from TLB.

MSDN [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)